# Does every client support SQLite3 triggers

Tags: sqlite, triggers

Lets say there is an SQLite3 database with a trigger, for example when a new row is inserted.

When a new row gets inserted, will that trigger (or better the respective callback function) always be carried out, no matter what client program was used?

Comment: Yes, triggers are server side.

Comment: You are certainly right regarding real client-server databases like MariaDB or Postgres etc. But what about SQLite3, where the client modifies a lokal (database-) file hence does not send queries to a server program.

Comment: A quick look at the documentation would have answered this. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html. Next time, check the manuals before you post here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I wasn't looking for the syntax how to create a trigger. I was asking whether each and every SQLite3-client supports that.
Next time, read the question before posting an inappropriate answer.

Comment: @Diani So, when you read the documentation, did you see any notes that might indicate that triggers are not supported? If not, why do you think that there might be problems? Why would the authoritative documentation not answer your question?

Comment: If the version of sqlite3 being used was compiled with `SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER` defined, triggers won't work.

Comment: @Tangentially Perpendicular  An SQLite-DB is, let me put it this way, a local file. It contains data, but (of course) no code. When you acceess the DB-file with a client program, for example written in C, R, Python, Matlab or whatever other language, where does this certain piece of code reside, which actually cares about the trigger? ...

Comment: ... When you use something like SQlite3.exe this piece of code is part of that exe-file. When you use a Python script that piece of code is in the included Python-library. But: What if - theoretically - the developer of the Python-library or Matlab-driver did just not implement trigger support? It's just not guaranteed, that the client supports triggers (or other features).

Comment: ... As Shawn wrote: When SQLite3.exe was compiled with SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER defined, triggers are not supported (see https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html ). That clearly shows, that even when the information about trigger conditions is stored _in_ the db-file, it's the client-program which has to take care about them - which is not guaranteed to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

> When a new row gets inserted, will that trigger (or better the respective callback function) always be carried out, no matter what client program was used?

Yes. SQLite is basically a file management system. If SQLite can be utilised then it very much functions exactly the same irrespective of the program(s) that use SQLite's interface. So as much as it supports inserts, deletes etc it will support triggers.

However, the version of SQLite installed may impose restrictions due to new features.

e.g. on 2022-09-29 Version 3.39.4 included:-

> Enhance SQLITE_DBCONFIG_DEFENSIVE so that it disallows CREATE TRIGGER statements if one or more of the statements in the body of the trigger write into shadow tables.

- https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html